# How to train continuous outputs(regression) in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, rbm, dbn

**I want to train regression model(not classification) which outputs are continuous numbers.**

Let's say I have input variable, X, which ranges between -70 to 70.
And I have output variable, Y, which ranges between -5 to 5. X has 39 features and Y has 16 features and they have 50,000 examples each. Then I would like to train them with deep belief network(DBN) in python.

I used the script in theano homepage which described DBN with MNIST data(classification). http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/DBN.html

Could you tell me what specific lines that I have to change in order to apply regression problem which I explained above?

For example I have to change...

1. sigmoid function to tanh function. : I heard tanh activation function works better than sigmoid in regression. right?
2. instead of using negative-log likelihood, I have to use least-square error....?
3. Input and output data normalization by zscore?

Please please let me know if you have any idea to solve this problem...
Most of the machine learning examples are based on MNIST hand digit classification. I would be happy if you recommend me some nice blogs or homepage where I can get useful information related to regression.

Thank you advance.

Comment: Just a general thought - **do not** start learning machine learning from deep models. It is like learning physics starting from quantum mechanics. Everyone that include deep learning in tutorials for newcomers simply have no idea what they are doing (and probably are newcomers themselfes). In short - if you ask such questions then deep models are not a good idea to start with, start with linear reggresion, then with with non-linear types like kernel regression, knn regression, rf regression, and so on. Otherwise you will fail, I guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

```
@hyungwon yang:
```

I haven't seen the python code but i think the following would be useful:

sigmoid function to tanh function: Not necessary, many publications use sigmoid for non linear regressions. To be frank, the choice is to be made from the type of data you have. I use sigmoid for many non linear models and it had worked for me.

least-square error: You can perform this by inbuilt Matlab function regress instead of confusing it with so many parameters.

Normalisations: You can do a min-max normalisation(refer Data Mining by Charu Agarwal), my implementation in Matlab is as follows:

```
%inputData: Is your N samples * of first feature, you have to iteratively do %this process for each and every feature.
function normOut = NormaliseAnyData (inputData)
denominator = (max(inputData) - min (inputData));
numerator = (inputData - min(inputData)); 
normOut = numerator/denominator;
end
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew what I'm doing there but I would like to listen to more heuristic comments. You gave me some!!